# Separate json labels and values with php

Tags: php, json

I have accessed this json file on my website:

```
[{
    "01:03:2016": "410",
    "02:03:2016": "200",
    "03:03:2016": "380"
}]
```

I want to use PHP to change the formatting to something like this, where the dates and counts are all values:

```
[{
    "date": "01:03:2016",
    "count": "410"
},
{
    "date": "02:03:2016",
    "count": "200"
},
{
    "date": "03:03:2016",
    "count": "380"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP

```
$string = file_get_contents("data.json"); // your current json data
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
$new_json = array();
foreach ($json_a as $key => $value) {
    $new_json[] = array("date"=>$key,'count'=>$value);
}
echo json_encode($new_json); //output
```

data.json file (your current data)

```
[{
    "01:03:2016": "410",
    "02:03:2016": "200",
    "03:03:2016": "380"
}]
```

Comment: In the foreach loop, it worked when I removed the [0] after $json_a.